# How to create a 1px border grid

Tags: android

I would like to create a clean grid.
I already have something that work, but I have a 2px border.
Here is my code :

In an activity :

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gvGame);
ButtonAdapter buttonAdapter = new ButtonAdapter(GameActivity.this, myList.getList());
gridview.setAdapter(buttonAdapter);
```

activity_game.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gvGame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Somewhere in ButtonAdapter :

```
button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grid_button);
```

grid_button.xml (drawable) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/black" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="1px"
        android:left="1px"
        android:right="1px"
        android:top="1px">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Result :

[image]

How can I get a 1px bordered grid everywhere ?

Note: each square must be clickable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about giving a `1px` border on your `RelativeLayout`'s `top` and `left` side and `1px` border on each cell's `right` and `bottom` side?

This will make the effect you want, but not sure what you want the result to be if the number of cells in the last row is less.

Comment: Good idea. I just had to add a bit of padding on my gridview to make the border visible. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to use the [spacing attributes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#attr_android:horizontalSpacing) of the GridView instead to achieve uniformly spaced grid.

```
<GridView
    ...
    android:horizontalSpacing="1px"
    android:verticalSpacing="1px"
    ... />
```

This creates a space between the GridView's items with the size of 1px.

If you want the spacing to be black, you have to set the GridView's (or its parent's) background to black.

Of course now you have to remove the black border of your button's background.

Comment: A usable solution. I guess it would do the trick, but this involves a bit of overdrawing.